# Compact subset of a space

Tags: general-topology

Consider the topological space $X=\{0,1\}^{\mathbb{Z}}\times \mathbb{Z}$ and let $Y$ be a subset of $X$ given by $Y=\{0,1\}^{\mathbb{Z}}\times\{0,1,2,\cdots\}$. Is $Y$ compact subset of $X$?

Set $U_k=\{0,1\}^{\mathbb{Z}}\times\{k\}$. Then $\{U_k
; k=0,1,2,\cdots\}$ is an open cover of $Y$ having no subcover. So $Y$ cannot be compact. Am I correct?

Comment: Yes, that’s correct.

Comment: It is correct assuming that $\mathbb Z$ is given the usual discrete topology.

Comment: Or use that the product of sets compact implies that all factors are too.

Comment: Ya Z is given discrete topology

Comment: @HennoBrandsma Thank you so much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you are correct. More generally, if $X$ is any nonempty topological space and $Y$ is infinite discrete, then $X\times Y$ is never compact. That's because $\big\{X\times\{y\}\big\}_{y\in Y}$ is an open cover without finite subcover.